# Excel - Problem with circular reference using offset formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset, circular-reference

I used the offset formula in cell R22 to find the average of the last 12 months taxes. I need to use the Q21 cell as the reference because whenever there are new taxes, i just add it in the left side. For example, if I need to add a new tax, 34.88% will be in S21 and the new tax i will place it in R21.

The returning value of the formula is correct, however, Excel is pointing out a circular reference in this cell in the bottom of the page, next to "Ready". When I go in formulas -> Error Checking, it appears a message telling me "The error checking is complete for the entire sheet". Also, when I go in Formulas -> Error Checking, the section of circular reference is grayed and I can't click on it.
Does anyone know why it's pointing out a circular reference and how can I fix it?

[image]
[image]

Thanks,

Isabela.

Answer (score 0):

Are the values in S21 to AD21 formulas or Values? It's not the formula in R22 which is giving you the circular reference but rather one of the inputs into it.

Drop down the error checking arrow and click trace error. It should show you where it is.

Comment: Hey Dan, the values in R21 to AD21 are all values. When I click in R23 and then in trace error the message is "The Trace Error command requires that the active cell contain an error value".

Comment: What happens if you click down the bottom in the task bar where it says there is an error?

Comment: Do you mean when I click in "Circular Reference: R22"? Nothing, it's very strange.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, it is indeed strange, maybe someone else on here will have an idea but it's got me stumped.